# Insert element directly into div using Jquery ui Droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this system to create a list of chosen images by dragging and dropping the image items into a div `id="trash"`.

This system is a copy from the photo manager in the jquery ui page:
[Link](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager)

What I'm trying to implement is to have a arrow-up icon in each image sample to have it be inserted into the list without having to drag it.

I've managed to append the element but I'm having trouble to call the function deleteImage() so it animates like the animation after you drop the element inside the list.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/circle73/gqSaq/3/) of the project

This is what I have so far:

```
$('a.quick_insert').click( function(){
  var sample = $("<li />").append($(this).closest($('li')).clone()).html();
  $(this).closest($('li')).fadeOut(function(){
    $('#trash').append(sample).fadeIn(function() {
      var $list = $( "ul", $trash ).length ?
      $( "ul", $trash ) :
      $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo( $trash );

      $sample.find( "a.ui-icon-trash" ).remove();
      $sample.append( recycle_icon ).appendTo( $list ).fadeIn(function() {
        $sample.animate({ width: "48px" }).find( "img" ).animate({ height: "36px" });
      });

    });
  });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change your code in:

```
// Quick Insertion
$('a.quick_insert').click( function(){
    deleteImage( $(this).parent() );
});
```

so you will reuse the same function of the example by passing the current clicked container as element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gqSaq/5/

### EDIT

To let the recycle work correctly you must delegate its click usin `on`, because the element is dynamically created.

Code:

```
// Quick Insertion
$('#gallery li').on('click', 'a.quick_insert', function () {
   deleteImage($(this).parent());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gqSaq/6/

Comment: It is exactly this! Thank you @Irvin. I have just one problem, when I submit the image by clicking the arrow and than recycle it and put it back in it's place, the arrow stops working